# VBA Macro WeekNum not defined

Tags: vba, excel, week-number

I'm trying to concancenate Year with WeekNum in VBA. But it said that the WeekNum Sub or Function does not defined.
How can I solve this? Here is my code :

```
For lrow = EndRow To 2 Step -1
    CurrentSheet.Cells(lrow, "AC").Value = _
    CONCATENATE(Year(CurrentSheet.Cells(lrow, "K").Value), _
    "/", Text(WeekNum(CurrentSheet.Cells(lrow, "K").Value), "00"))
Next lrow
```

*Note that I do this a line only, just using _ just for reading capability

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Application.WorksheetFunction` in front:

```
For lrow = EndRow To 2 Step -1
    CurrentSheet.Cells(lrow, "AC").Value = _
    CONCATENATE(Year(CurrentSheet.Cells(lrow, "K").Value), _
    "/", Text(Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(CurrentSheet.Cells(lrow, "K").Value), "00"))
Next lrow
```

Comment: Thanks @jeff-carey ! :)